# what does this mean in detail? -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash

Tags: directory, root

can anybody help me with what this means: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash` and explain it in detail.

Answer (score 2):

It says that the file `bash` has :

- a size of 920788 bytes
- is owned by user 'root' from group 'root' (1st root is user, and 2nd is group)
- the user root can read/write/execute file (rwx on the left)
- users from group root can read/execute file (r-x in the middle)
- all other users can read/execute file (r-x on the right)
  the - means it is a normal file and the 1 links it to files.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the "-" before the first r in "-rwxr-xr-x" describes what type the entry is. For example "-" is a normal file, d is for a directory and l is for symbolic links.

Comment: Yes, i forgot it ;)